# Minimun TLS version not set using python-ldap module

Tags: ssl, ldap, tls1.2, starttls, python-ldap

I have set the min TLS version for ldap using ldap.OPT_X_TLS_PROTOCOL_MIN

`conn.set_options(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_PROTOCOL_MIN, 0x304) //0x304 is TLS1.3`

Even after this ,in the pcap file ,the record layer TLS 1.0 is used and the client hello was sent on TLS1.2. Please refer for the wireshark screenshot below.

[image]

I dont understand even after setting the ldap.OPT_X_TLS_PROTOCOL_MIN to TLS1.3 why is it negotiating in TLS1.2. My device doesnt support TLS1.3,hence the connection should throw an error.
Please assist me.

Comment: You should get some info about SSL/TLS version range with `ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 255)`.

Comment: Tried but its bot helping